RabbitMQ consumer doesn't receive subsequent message if I try sending it too fast after the first one was received
I have this problem where when I immediately send a new message to my consumer in Kotlin after processing the last message, it won't receive and process the second message, but if I wait some time (like a few minutes, didn't bother to get the exact time) and send a new message again my consumer receives it and processes it. I'm 100% sure the  new message gets sent because I see the message graph in the rabbit mq dashboard go up. I want my rabbit mq consumer to be fast enough to process multiple messages, but not at the same time, one by one.
Here's my RabbitMQConfig
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Value("\${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    lateinit var rabbitmqHost: String

    @Value("\${rabbitmq.queue}")
    lateinit var queueName: String

    @Bean
    fun queue(): Queue {
        return Queue(queueName)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jsonMessageConverter(): MessageConverter {
        return Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()
    }

    @Bean
    fun listenerAdapter(receiver: RabbitMQReceiver, converter: MessageConverter): MessageListenerAdapter {
        val adapter = MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage")
        adapter.setMessageConverter(converter)
        return adapter
    }

    @Bean
    fun container(
        connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
        listenerAdapter: MessageListenerAdapter
    ): SimpleMessageListenerContainer {
        return SimpleMessageListenerContainer().apply {
            this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory
            this.setQueueNames(queueName)
            this.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter)
            this.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false)
        }
    }
}
 

And here's my RabbitMQReceiver class (My consumer)
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

object MessageConstant {
    const val DATA_MESSAGE_KEY = "data"
    const val TOPIC_MESSAGE_KEY = "topic"
    const val TYPE_MESSAGE_KEY = "type"
}

@Component
class RabbitMQReceiver(
    private val productStrategy: ProductStrategy,
    private val supplierStrategy: SupplierStrategy,
    private val supplierStockScheduleStrategy: SupplierStockScheduleStrategy,
    private val productCategoryStrategy: ProductCategoryStrategy,
    private val deliveryDriverStrategy: DeliveryDriverStrategy,
    private val vehicleStrategy: VehicleStrategy,
) {
    private val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    fun receiveMessage(message: Map<String, Any>) {
        val topic = message[MessageConstant.TOPIC_MESSAGE_KEY] as? String
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Topic key is missing in the message")
        val messageType = message[MessageConstant.TYPE_MESSAGE_KEY] as? String
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Message type key is missing in the message")

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val data = message[MessageConstant.DATA_MESSAGE_KEY] as? Map<String, Any>
        data?.let {
            val topicStrategy = getTopicStrategy(topic)
            when (messageType) {
                MessageType.Upsert.name -> topicStrategy.upsert(it)
                MessageType.Unpublish.name -> topicStrategy.delete(it)
                MessageType.Delete.name -> topicStrategy.delete(it, softDelete = true)
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported action: $messageType")
            }
        } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Data key is missing or invalid in the message")
        latch.countDown()
    }

    private fun getTopicStrategy(topic: String): TopicStrategy {
        return when (topic) {
            Topic.Product.name -> productStrategy
            Topic.Supplier.name -> supplierStrategy
            Topic.SupplierStockSchedule.name -> supplierStockScheduleStrategy
            Topic.ProductCategory.name -> productCategoryStrategy
            Topic.DeliveryDriver.name -> deliveryDriverStrategy
            Topic.Vehicle.name -> vehicleStrategy
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported topic: $topic")
        }
    }

    fun getLatch(): CountDownLatch {
        return latch
    }
}

